# Git Squash all commits in origin/master into single commit within origin/master

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was playing around with my git repository and made quite a number of commits earlier on to master branch. Now I realised that it is a bit too noisy, and will like to merge all of that into a single commit.

```
102381 commit z
....
176232 commit a
891273 initial commit
```

to simply

```
198273 initial commit (after rebase)
891273 initial commit
```

I have looked around and many of the solutions seems to be around squashing. Unfortunately that might be possible given that everything is on the master branch already.

One of my initial thoughts was to

1. create a new branch from commit #891273
2. squash everything from master into the new branch
3. delete the old master, and replace it with this new branch

I am not sure if this might be a good way to do it; thought it will be wiser to get some ideas, guidance and discussions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an easy way to achieve your requirement:

1. `git checkout –b  branch1`. Create a new branch from commit #891273,
2. `git rebase –i master`
3. waiting for editor to input (type `i` to start input):

   `pick 176232 commit a`

   `squash ****** commit b`

   `......`

   `squash 102381 commit z`

note: type ‘Esc’ button to stop input

4. input `:wq` to exit the editor, then you will find what you want

Note: when squashing commit a to z, it may have conflict. You need to fix the conflicted file, and use git add filename, git rebase --continue to continue squashing

Reference：
https://makandracards.com/makandra/527-squash-several-git-commits-into-a-single-commit

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do a soft reset to `891273` followed by a commit.
This will reset the branch to the first commit, keeping the reset of the changes in the staging area, which you can commit in the next step.

```
git reset --soft 891273 
git commit -m 'Second Commit'
```

This way you will have two commits in your repository.

Comment: Additionally, you may need to run `git push --force`.